# Solving $\min_{\Phi} \sum_i \| zero\_diag (\Phi^T A_i \Phi) \|_F^2 s.t. \Phi^T \Phi = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a set of real symmetric matrices $\boldsymbol{A}_1,\dots,\boldsymbol{A}_n$. I need to find the orthogonal matrix $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ that solves:

$\min_{\boldsymbol{\Phi}}\sum_i \|$zero_diag($\boldsymbol{\Phi}^T \boldsymbol{A}_i \boldsymbol{\Phi}$) $\|_F^2$ s.t. $\boldsymbol{\Phi}^T \boldsymbol{\Phi} = \boldsymbol{\Phi} \boldsymbol{\Phi}^T = \boldsymbol{I}$.

Here, zero_diag does the following: 1. takes a matrix, 2. zeros its diagonal entries, 3. returns the resulted matrix.
For example: zero_diag($[1 \, 2; 3 \, 4]$)=$[0 \, 2; 3 \, 0]$.

Is there a closed form for $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ (perhaps in terms of eigenvectors of matrices)?

Comment: It is notable that this is equivalent to computing
$$
\max_{\Phi} \sum_i \|\operatorname{diag}(\Phi^TA_i\Phi)\|_F^2
$$
where
$$
\operatorname{diag}\pmatrix{1&2\\3&4} = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&4}
$$

Comment: Also: if $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are the columns of $\Phi$, then we can write
$$
\|\operatorname{diag}(\Phi^TA\Phi)\|_F^2 = \sum_{j=1}^k (v_j^T A v_j)^2
$$

Comment: Do you know of any result in the case where our set contains only the matrix $A_1$?

Comment: $\Phi^TA\Phi$ has the same off-diagonal part as $\Phi^T(A+cI)\Phi$. Therefore you can make each $A_i$ positive definite *before* performing any other transformation. I think this will make your problem a bit easier. The resulting objective function $\sum_{i,j}\|A_i^{1/2}v_j\|^4$ (where the $v_j$s are orthonormal) is quartic. I don't think there is any closed-form solution.

Comment: I suspect that the [Schur-Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) will be useful here

Comment: For a set of $1$ matrix, it suffices to choose a $\Phi$ that diagonalizes $A_1$

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how. Doesn't the diag operator inside $\| .\|_F^2$ hinder your diagonalization argument?

Comment: @Golabi if $\Phi^T A\Phi$ is diagonal, then 
$$
\|\text{zero\_diag}(\Phi^TA\Phi)\|_F^2 = 0,
$$
which is clearly the smallest possible outcome.